# Python itertools.product with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am trying to write a module to combine a variable number of lists using itertools.product.

The closest I can get is:

```
import itertools
lists = [["item1","item2"],["A","b","C"], ["etc..."]]
searchterms = list(itertools.product(lists))
print searchterms
```

This doesn't work, because lists is a single list, so it just returns the original sequence. But I can't figure out how to pass each element of the lists variable to itertools.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `*` to separate the single list into its constituent lists:

```
searchterms = list(itertools.product(*lists))
```

See the Python Tutorial section on [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thanks! where can I find documentation on *var ?