# Create all possible char combinations from an unknown amount of lists in python

Tags: python, string, list, char, combinatorics

I want to create all possible character combinations from lists. The first char needs to be from the first array, the second char from the second array, etc.

If I have the following lists:

```
char1 = ['a','b','c']
char2 = ['1','2']
```

The possible strings, would be: a1, a2, b1, b2, c1 and c2.
How do I make the code with makes all the combinations from an unknown amount of lists with an unknown size?

The problem is that I do not know, how many lists there will be. The amount of lists will be decided by the user, while the code is running.

Comment: This one is for an unknown amount of lists, therefore the two list multiplication code isn't useful here.

Comment: "The amount of lists will be decided by the user, while the code is running." Then they will certainly not be in separate variables, but in a list of lists instead... **right**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use `itertools.product()`

And since you don't know number of lists you can pass list of lists as an argument:

```
import itertools

lists = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['1','2']
]

["".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*lists)]
```

Result:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a task for `itertools.product()`! Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
>>> ["%s%s" % (c1,c2) for (c1,c2) in itertools.product(char1, char2)]
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2']
```

And yeah, it extends to a variable number of lists of unknown size.

Comment: But how can it be modified so it works for an unknown amount of lists?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148834/python-itertools-product-with-variable-number-of-arguements